# Is it possible to sort a list of objects depending on the individual object's response to a method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am wanting to display a gallery of `products` where I include products that are both for sale and not for sale.  Only I want the `products` that are for sale to appear at the front of the list and the objects that are not for sale  will appear at the end of the list.

An easy way for me to accomplish this is to make two lists, then merge them (one list of on_sale? objects and one list of not on_sale? objects):

```
available_products = []
sold_products = []
@products.each do |product|
  if product.on_sale?
    available_products << product
  else
    sold_products << product
  end
end
```

. . . But do to the structure of my existing app, this would require an excessive amount of refactoring due to an oddity in my code (I lose my pagination, and I would rather not refactor).  It would be easier if there were a way to sort the existing list of objects by my `product` model's method `on_sale?` which returns a boolean value.

**Is it possible to more elegantly iterate through an existing list and sort it by this true or false value in rails?**  I only ask because there is so much I'm not aware of hidden within this framework / language (ruby) and I'd like to know if they work has been done before me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure. Ideally we'd do something like this using [`sort_by!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21):

```
@products.sort_by! {|product| product.on_sale?}
```

or the snazzier

```
@products.sort_by!(&:on_sale?)
```

but sadly, `<=>` doesn't work for booleans (see [Why doesn't sort or the spaceship (flying saucer) operator (<=>) work on booleans in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816131/why-doesnt-sort-or-the-flying-saucer-operator-work-on-booleans-in-ruby)) and `sort_by` doesn't work for boolean values, so we need to use this trick (thanks rohit89!)

```
@products.sort_by! {|product| product.on_sale? ? 0 : 1}
```

---

If you want to get fancier, the `sort` method takes a block, and inside that block you can use whatever logic you like, including type conversion and multiple keys. Try something like this:

```
@products.sort! do |a,b|
  a_value = a.on_sale? ? 0 : 1
  b_value = b.on_sale? ? 0 : 1
  a_value <=> b_value
end
```

or this:

```
@products.sort! do |a,b|
  b.on_sale?.to_s <=> a.on_sale?.to_s
end
```

(putting b before a because you want `"true"` values to come before `"false"`)

or if you have a secondary sort:

```
@products.sort! do |a,b|
  if a.on_sale? != b.on_sale?
    b.on_sale?.to_s <=> a.on_sale?.to_s
  else
    a.name <=> b.name
  end
end
```

Note that `sort` returns a new collection, which is usually a cleaner, less error-prone solution, but [`sort!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) modifies the contents of the original collection, which you said was a requirement.

Comment: Looks great! But I am having problems with it with my specific code, maybe you can help me with it.  If I use the one-liner I get the following error `comparison of FalseClass with true failed`, and if I use the first code you mentioned, I get `comparison of [MyModule]::Product with [MyModule]::Product failed`.  Not sure why this would fail.

Comment: Some notes: 1) One should use always `sort_by` over `sort` whenever possible (more declarative, more concise, more efficient). It's possible to use it in all snippets shown above. 2) It may me preferable to link to the non-destructive `Enumerable#sort_by`, in-place updates should be avoided whenever possible. 3) `@product.sort_by(&:on_sale?)`.

Comment: Looks like `<=>` doesn't work right for booleans (in ruby-1.9.3-p327). Looking into it now... Yeah, http://grosser.it/2010/07/30/ruby-true-false-comparison-with/ confirms it for an earlier version

Comment: Updated answer, and incorporated tokland's sort_by advice

Comment: I worked out a solution using your answer in a different area of my app - a little less elegant, but this post is what got me there.  Marked as the answer.

Comment: I just asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816131/why-doesnt-sort-or-the-flying-saucer-operator-work-on-booleans-in-ruby

Answer (score 5):

`@products.sort_by {|product| product.on_sale? ? 0 : 1}`

This is what I did when I had to sort based on booleans.

Answer (score 5):

No need to sort:

```
products_grouped = @products.partition(&:on_sale?).flatten(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ascending and descending can be done by inter changing "false" and "true"

```
Products.sort_by {|product| product.on_sale? ==  true ? "false" : "true" }
```